# Print a rectangle with diagonals using a 2d array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, printing, console

I have been trying to modify the normal rectangle 2d array, that is printed to the console, to show the diagonals of it as well with a different character. For example, my current code for a rectangle with a 2d array is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RecArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Height: ");
    int height = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Width: ");
    int width = scanner.nextInt();


    char[][] square = new char[height][width];

    String line;

    // fill the array
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        square[i][j] = 'o';
      }
    }

    // print the array
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      line = "";
      for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        line += square[i][j];
      }
      System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
```

and it returns:

```
Height: 10
Width: 10
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
```

I want my diagonal code to return:

```
Height: 5
Width: 7
xooooox
oxoooxo
ooxxxoo
oxoooxo
xooooox
```

My current code is:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    class RecArrayDiag {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Height: ");
        int height = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Width: ");
        int width = scanner.nextInt();

        char[][] square = new char[height][width];
        boolean bool1 = true;
        boolean bool2 = true;
        boolean bool3 = true;
        boolean bool4 = true;
        String line;
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = width-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (i % 2 == 0 ? ((i == height/2)) : ((i == height-1/2))) {
                    bool1 = false;
                }
                if (j % 2 == 0 ? ((j == width/2)) : ((j == width-1/2))) {
                    bool2 = false;
                }

                if ((((i == j) && bool1 && bool2) || (i == (height - (j+1))) || (j == (width - (i+1))) || ((j == width-1) && bool3) || ((i == height-1) && bool4) || (j == width-1) && (i == height-1))) {
                    square[i][j] = 'x';
                    //x++;
                } else {
                    square[i][j] = 'o';
                }
                if ((j == width-1)) {
                    bool3 = false;
                }
                if ((i == height-1)) {
                    bool4 = false;
                }
            }
            x++;
        }

        // print the array
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            line = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                line += square[i][j];
            }
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

And this returns:

```
Height: 5
Width: 7
xoooxox
oxoxoxo
ooxoxoo
oxoxooo
xoxooox
```

Please help me in solving this problem and thanks in advance.

Comment: *Unrelated hint:* To print, you can do `for (char[] line : square) { System.out.println(line); }` which uses the [`println(char[] x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-char:A-) method.

Comment: *FYI:* A [**square**](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/square.html) has the same width and height. When width and height may differ, it's called a [rectangle](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/rectangle.html). Your `square` variable is misnamed.

Comment: int 1/2 is always 0

Comment: Oh, I see. It's even worse: you should put brackets there: (width - 1)/2

Comment: Very hard to follow. Please explain your logic to find out the diagonals. All those bools, please explain.

Comment: I think the methodology is plain wrong: you'll never get a diagonal printing cells with x == y. That'll work for squares, not rectangles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i understand it you'd like to display some sort of a cross.
And you want to handle the case where the matrix is not a square.

That means you could directly go from all corners to the center point and if one axis reaches the middle of the array first just stop the counter and proceed with the second param.

something like that (just pseudo code):

```
//create square with "o" everywhere then overwrite
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while(i < height/2 || j < width/2){

    //go from all corners towards the middle
    if (i == j){
       square[i][j] = "x";
       square[i][width - j+1] = "x";
       square[height - i+1][j] = "x";
       square[height - i+1][width - j+1] = "x";
    } else if (i < height/2) { //i is in middle of array
       square[i][j] = "x";
       square[i][width - j+1] = "x";
    } else { //j is is in middle of array
       square[i][j] = "x";
       square[height - i+1][j] = "x";
    }

    //as long i and j did not reach the center add 1
    if (i < width/2) { i++ }
    if (j < height/2) { j++ }
}
```

Hope this helps a bit.
In general i would advise splitting up your problem in different parts.

I can see the logic in your solution but try to keep it simple.
Find rules that work as long as a condition is true.
(In this case: as long as you are not in the middle of any array)
Then try to find a solution for cases that are not true. (e.g what happens if i reaches the middle of the array but j doesnt)

Like that you can split up your code and make it much easier to read/maintain.

In most cases where you have huge if else statements there is a big chance you can rewrite them into smaller parts.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it, with reusable method separating the various operations applied to the rectangle.

```
public static void printRectangleWithDiagonals(int width, int height) {
    char[][] rectangle = new char[height][width];
    fill(rectangle, 'o');
    drawDiagonals(rectangle, 'x');
    print(rectangle);
}
private static void fill(char[][] rectangle, char ch) {
    for (char[] line : rectangle)
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++)
            line[i] = ch;
}
private static void drawDiagonals(char[][] rectangle, char ch) {
    int bottom = rectangle.length - 1, right = rectangle[0].length - 1;
    if (right > bottom) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= right; x++) {
            int y = (x * bottom + right / 2) / right;
            rectangle[y][x] = ch;
            rectangle[bottom - y][x] = ch;
        }
    } else {
        for (int y = 0; y <= bottom; y++) {
            int x = (y * right + bottom / 2) / bottom;
            rectangle[y][x] = ch;
            rectangle[y][right - x] = ch;
        }
    }
}
private static void print(char[][] rectangle) {
    for (char[] line : rectangle)
        System.out.println(line);
}
```

*Test*

```
printRectangleWithDiagonals(7, 7);
System.out.println();
printRectangleWithDiagonals(10, 4);
System.out.println();
printRectangleWithDiagonals(5, 9);
```

*Output*

```
xooooox
oxoooxo
ooxoxoo
oooxooo
ooxoxoo
oxoooxo
xooooox

xxooooooxx
ooxxxxxxoo
ooxxxxxxoo
xxooooooxx

xooox
oxoxo
oxoxo
ooxoo
ooxoo
oxoxo
oxoxo
xooox
xooox
```